# Regex for a string that must contain an uppercase letter, a lower case letter, a digit, a printable ASCI character with no white spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

Help me write a JavaScript regex for a string that can contain:

- An uppercase letter. (at least 1)
- A lowercase letter. (at least 1)
- A number (at least 1)
- A printable ASCII character (optional)
- No whitespaces.

Example:

"NewYork12@" can be a valid string.
"New York12@" is an invalid string.

What I tried:

`/(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d](?=.*[!-~])/`

This is not working as it accepts whitespace as well.

Thanks.

Comment: One of each? Use 4 independent regular expressions and combine their result with `&&` in your host language (JavaScript)

Answer (score 1):

I would just use `\S+` as the actual pattern to be matched here, keeping your positive lookaheads in place:

```
/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)\S+$/
```

This pattern says to:

```regex
^            from the start of the input
(?=.*[a-z])  assert lowercase letter present
(?=.*[A-Z])  assert uppercase letter present
(?=.*\d)     assert digit present
\S+          then match one or more exclusively non whitespace characters
$            end of the input
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This actually works. I just modified it a bit to support ASCII. The final looks like this.

/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!-~])\S+$/

Comment: @AabishkarWagle I didn't consider ASCII vs. non ASCII, as your printable ASCII character requirement was labelled "optional."

Answer (score 0):

Negative matches can be very difficult to properly express in a regular expression. It is often simpler to not express *everything* as a single regex. Use multiple regular expressions and combine their result in the host language:

```
if (
  input.match(/[A-Z]/)      // at least 1 upper case letter
    && input.match(/[a-z]/) // at least 1 lower case letter
    && input.match(/[0-9]/) // at least 1 digit
    && !input.match(/\s/)   // no whitespace
) {
  // all rules fulfilled
}
```